# How to use python imshow, for example, with the irregular data points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, wolfram-mathematica, density-plot

Suppose I have a list of data points of the form `(xi, yi, zi)` and I want to plot a 2D density plot with it. In mathematica, you just call the function `ListDensityPlot` function. In python, it seems density plot is achieved by using `imshow`. However, it seems the required data should be in regular form. How to get the similar effect given the data sets?

Here is the mathematica code:

```
n = 100;
xs = RandomReal[1, n];
ys = RandomReal[1, n];
zs = xs + ys;
data = Table[{xs[[i]], ys[[i]], zs[[i]]}, {i, n}];
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The effect of the above code is (of course, one can set the range to remove the white regions):

[image]

In python, I have generated the data, how to throw it into a function `list_density_plot` to achieve similar effects?

```
def f(x, y):
    return x+y

N = 100
xs = np.random.random(N)
ys = np.random.random(N)
zs = f(xs, ys)

data = [(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i]) for i in range(N)]
list_density_plot(data)  # ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`plt.tricontourf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) or [`plt.tripcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor.html).

Example with `plt.tripcolor`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def f(x, y):
    return x + y


N = 100
xs = np.random.random(N)
ys = np.random.random(N)
zs = f(xs, ys)

plt.tripcolor(xs, ys, zs)
plt.show()
```

[image]